# Concatenate MP3s in Scala / Java

Tags: java, scala, audio

I'm trying to concatenate mp3s in Scala, although I'm actually using mainly Java libraries. So far I've put the requisite stuff on my CLASSPATH ( see here: http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html for details of how to read mp3s)
and written the following:

```
import java.io._;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;


object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fileA = "Track 0000.mp3"
    val fileB = "Track 0001.mp3"

    try {
      var ClipA = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileA))
      var ClipB = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileB))

      var appendedFiles = new AudioInputStream(
                                new SequenceInputStream(ClipA, ClipB),     
                                ClipA.getFormat(), 
                                ClipA.getFrameLength() + ClipB.getFrameLength());


    } catch {
      case ioe: IOException => println(ioe.getMessage())
      case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage())
    }

  }
}
```

But I'm now struggling to write the mp3s to the disk. Can anyone help me out? How is this done?

Comment: You can actually just concatenate MP3 files. Some of the ID3/metadata will be off, but that's not a problem for many applications.

Answer (score 0):

The `AudioSystem` class has an helper method to do this, [`AudioSystem.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#write%28javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat.Type,%20java.io.File%29):

```
public static int write(AudioInputStream stream, AudioFileFormat.Type fileType,
                          File out) throws IOException
```

You should be able to do something like:

```
AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, mp3AudioType, new File("/tmp/out.mp3"))
```

With `mp3AudioType` being the right [`AudioFileFormat.Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFileFormat.Type.html) for mp3; maybe just `AudioFileFormat.Type("MP3", "mp3")` would work.